# How do I make a nav bar fixed to the middle with custom icons and not fa fa icons?

Tags: html, css, nav

How do I make a nav bar with custom icons instead of the fa fa-icons?

Comment: Please add tags and more details of your question.

Comment: You can create some black space in starting then you get your menu list fixed at the center. Could have helped you more if you had some code written on your question.